# comparing data between two different table in same database

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with same schema , and primary key as noc for both,

whenever insert is made in table 1 , its noc must be checked in TABLE2, if exist then complete row must be compared and  if there is any difference an exception must be raised .
and if noc does not exist in TABLE2 then simple insertion must follow

this is my trigger function

```
          CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ac_val()
           RETURNS trigger AS
           $BODY$

            BEGIN

           IF NEW.acop IS NULL THEN

                           INSERT INTO exception_detail( noc,exception) 
    VALUES (new.noc,'number cannot be empty');


    END IF;


    RETURN NEW;
           END;
   $BODY$
       LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

this is my trigger

```
             CREATE TRIGGER acut_val
           AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
             ON acut
          FOR EACH ROW
         EXECUTE PROCEDURE ac_val();
```

this is perfectly ok for one table, 
 but now according to requirement on every insert it must check if noc exists in other table, TABLE2 , 
if exist then comparison must be made, otherwise insertion

I think I can not perform that check on each insert because data to be inserted in acuit is to be copied from csv, and  that will require copy from csv, and if i do copy  it gives error u must be super user, but if i copy from console its ok. 
So can i do something like after data is copied in acuit making a check row by row

```
             SELECT q1.* FROM acut q1
             INNER JOIN TABLE2 q2 ON (q1.noc = q2.noc);
```

it will give records of acut which exists in TABLE2

and then

```
              foreach row of above output{

      if (q1.name != q2.name)
      Do something ;

    if (q2.address < q1.address)
     Do something ;

     }
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Comment: And what requirement are you trying to fulfil by designing such a system?

Comment: @Colin'tHart: Thank u for ur reply, its a validation plan, data must be checked against other table,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to use a trigger on `table1`.

Don't use the trigger to check uniqueness because you can't see uncommitted data from other users.

Instead use the trigger to `INSERT` the data into `table2` -- which should have a unique constraint on all the columns you want to check.

If you insert data into table1 that already exists in table2, the unique constraint on table2 will be violated, raising an exception which you can catch in your front end.

The big advantage to this approach is that it will also work correctly for multi-user situations where your transaction can't see uncommitted data in table2 but the DBMS will still prevent the insert from continuing (the transaction will hang until the other transaction either `commit`s or `rollback`s).

Comment: Thank u Colin, but  i want if data exist in TABLE2 then each column of table1 must be compared with each column of TABLE2 , and if mismatch then raise exception .and if data of that number does not exist in TABLE2 then insert in TABLE1, and I am very new to postgresql, i am finding it difficult with syntax

Comment: And what I described here will do that. It might not work if your table is too wide (if Postgres has a limitation on width of index). And the data is inserted, so if you don't want an extra copy you should delete the row again in the trigger.

Comment: means i must make one trigger on table2, trying to insert data in TABLE2, if data already exist and different then it must raise exception, I will try and post code,and den will accept ur answer thank u very much for ur help,

Comment: All the (on insert) trigger needs to do is insert the row into table2. The unique constraint on table2 will do the testing for you.

Comment: If i am setting all the elements to unique then i can not have two rows with same value, my primary key is just noc on which all comparison is to be made, while others can have same data in different rows, i am sorry to bother u again n again